# Unable to create an unordered list with <ul> with my linked CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I can only create an unordered list with `<u1>` ("you one") and not `<ul>` ("you el") when I reference any html document in its `<head>` with my css stylesheet this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/default.css" />
```

Every other css design modification works, except I lose the ability to make unordered lists with `<ul>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/default.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!--This doesnt work-->
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <!--But somehow this does-->
    <u1>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </u1>

</body>

</html>
```

Result:
[image: result]

Edited with HTML and result

Below is my CSS stylesheet, is there anything funny going on in it? Thanks!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana,arial; 
}

body {
    display: block;
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5% 0.5%;
}

p {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

table {
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: smaller;
}

th, td {
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
}

a {
    text-decoration-line: none; 
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    cursor: hand;
}

.header {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.loginbox {
    display:block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.mainmenu {
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    width: 67.5%;
    margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5% 0.5%;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    float: right;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5% 0% 0% 0%;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.advertisement {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.menuHeader1 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
}

.menuHeader2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;   
    background-color: silver;
}

.secondaryMenu {
    margin-left: 15px;  
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.cellnumber {
    text-align: right;
}

.rowheader {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please edit and show your HTML.  `<u1>` is not a recognised HTML listing tag. You may be wanting `<ol>` for *ordered* list...

Comment: I have edited the post. My problem stems from <ul> not working when I link my css stylesheet, but working without.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you try to replace `<u1>`  with anything valid?

Comment: Yes I have tried replacing <u1> with <ul>, it does not work. I tried having a clean html document that does not reference my css stylesheet and both <u1> and <ul> worked fine. The issue thus lies with my css stylesheet but I fail to see where.

Comment: And what have you tried to check for problems? Current browsers provide excellent debugging capabilities for CSS. Also, why not remove one CSS definition after the other to check which one causes the problem?

Comment: Hi, this has been answered. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this and am not sure what you mean by browser debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from your over-zealous CSS reset:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana,arial; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

List elements require padding on the left for the bullet to be shown:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana,arial; 
}
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was also going to say this, seems like you are just hiding the bullet points so adding a little bit of space for them to be shown should solve it

Comment: This solved it! I had no idea the default padding is not 0 and having it as 0 would mess with my list bullets as I didn't write this stylesheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not fixed with padding on the left to let the bullet points out I would recommend giving the  and try to access the individual unordered lists instead of changing both of them by calling the ul in the css.

Simply call the .testClass instead :)